# Reading Local File using Javascript in a NGINX Docker Container Fails with 404

Tags: javascript, docker, nginx

What is going wrong here? The Javascript in this website should live-tail the last 20 lines of a log into the page. The idea is to tail direct from the host by mounting the host file system into the container.  When viewed from inside the container (using VSCode's `connect to running container` feature) the directory the log is visible at the expected place. However the website (in Chrome) always returns a 404 in the console -

```
http://localhost:8088/    
script.js:19 

       GET http://localhost:8088/log/example.log 404 (Not Found)
```

It works fine if the log is `ADD`ed to the container, but this does not update as it is just a static copy taken at build time.

The container starts with a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
COPY ./script.js /usr/share/nginx/html/script.js
```

The command lines to build & start the container:

```
docker build -t webserver .
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8088:80 --name web --mount type=bind,source=/Users/username/projects/website,target=/log,readonly -d webserver
```

I've tried various mounting methods, all with the same result.

script.js

```
function fetchLogs() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', '/log/example.log');
  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status === 200) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
      //const logLines = JSON.parse(request.responseText); // For JSON formatted logs
      const logLines = request.responseText.split('\n');  // For plain text logs
      const logElement = document.getElementById('log-container');
      logElement.innerHTML = '';

      for (const logLine of logLines.slice(-20)) {
        const logItem = document.createElement('div');
        logItem.textContent = logLine;
        logElement.appendChild(logItem);
      }
    }
  };
  request.send();
}

fetchLogs();

setInterval(fetchLogs, 5000); // Fetch logs every 5 seconds
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log Tailer</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="fetchLogs()">
    <h2>Hello from Nginx container</h2>
    <div id="log-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any clues? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is quite obvious when you know what you are doing (which I don't, really) - there are two problems:

1. Mounting a directory from the local file system into the container file system works fine, but the NGINX web server root is not the root of the file system. The path `/log` in the `script.js` is `/usr/share/nginx/html/log` on the file system. Therefore it is necessary to mount the local log file to that location - see the `docker run` command below
2. Chrome caches the web page meaning that even if the container is stopped, removed and rebuilt completely it is possible that Chrome does not reload changes.

`docker run -it --rm -d -p 8088:80 --name web --mount type=bind,source=/Users/toby/work/projects/website,target=/usr/share/nginx/html/log,readonly -d webserver`

Thank you all for your attention, and happy holiday season.